# How do I allow all parameters even if they are blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have the following:

```
def index
  @dealFilter = DealFilter.new params[:deal_filter].permit(deal_filter: {})
```

It works when parameters are given, but not when they are missing. It gives ``` undefined method ``permit' for nil:NilClass Did you mean? print ``` error. I would like it to work in both cases.

- I tried `params[:deal_filter]` but it complained about `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`.
- I tried `params.permit(deal_filter: {})` but it said  `unknown attribute 'deal_filter' for DealFilter.`.
- I tried `params.permit(:deal_filter)` but it ignores the parameter values then: `Unpermitted parameters: utf8, deal_filter, commit`.

Comment: have you tried `params.fetch(:deal_filter, {}).permit(deal_filter: {})` ?

Comment: No I haven't, but it didn't work. `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "deal_filter"=>{"min"=>"", "max"=>"", "sector_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Filter"}` and `Unpermitted parameters: min, max, sector_id`.

Comment: so tried: `params.fetch(:deal_filter, {}).permit(:min, :max, :sector_id)` Because you don't post your form so I don't know what params are submitted.

Comment: That worked! `@dealFilter = DealFilter.new params.fetch(:deal_filter, {}).permit(:min, :max, :sector_id)`

Comment: Great, let me create an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If params is blank, we need to set a default value for it using `fetch`:

`params.fetch(:deal_filter, {}).permit(:some_params)`

so that `params[:deal_filter]` will be `{}` when it is missing.

From your errors, the final code should be:

`params.fetch(:deal_filter, {}).permit(:min, :max, :sector_id)`